# Assimp: Manipulate bones of rigged mesh manually

Tags: c#, 3d, assimp

I am working on a project which has following goal:

- Load rigged 3D mesh (e.g. a human skeleton) with Assimp.NET
- Manipulate bones of mesh so it fits your own body (with Microsoft Kinect v2)
- Perform vertex skinning

Loading the rigged mesh and extracting bone information works (hopefully) without any problems (based on this tutorial: http://www.richardssoftware.net/2013/10/skinned-models-in-directx-11-with.html). Each bone (class "ModelBone") consists of following information:

```
Assimp.Matrix4x4 LocalTransform
Assimp.Matrix4x4 GlobalTransform
Assimp.Matrix4x4 Offset
```

`LocalTransform` is directly extracted from assimp node (`node.Transform`).

`GlobalTransform` includes own `LocalTransform` and all parent's `LocalTransform` (see code snipped `calculateGlobalTransformation()`).

`Offset` is directly extracted from assimp bone (`bone.OffsetMatrix`).

At the moment I don't have GPU vertex skinning implemented, but I iterate over each vertex and manipulate it's position and normal vector.

```
        foreach (Vertex vertex in this.Vertices)
        {
            Vector3D newPosition = new Vector3D();
            Vector3D newNormal = new Vector3D();

            for (int i=0; i < vertex.boneIndices.Length; i++)
            {
                int boneIndex = vertex.boneIndices[i];
                float boneWeight = vertex.boneWeights[i];

                ModelBone bone = this.BoneHierarchy.Bones[boneIndex];

                Matrix4x4 finalTransform = bone.GlobalTransform * bone.Offset;

                // Calculate new vertex position and normal
                newPosition += boneWeight * (finalTransform * vertex.originalPosition);
                newNormal += boneWeight * (finalTransform * vertex.originalNormal);
            }

            // Apply new vertex position and normal
            vertex.position = newPosition;
            vertex.normal = newNormal;
        }
```

Like I already said, I want to manipulate bones with a Kinect v2 sensor, so I won't have to use animations (e.g. interpolating keyframes, ...)! But for the beginning I want to be able to manipulate bones manually (e.g. rotate torso of mesh by 90 degrees). Therefore I create a 4x4 rotation matrix (90 degrees around x-axis) by calling `Assimp.Matrix4x4.FromRotationX(1.5708f);`. Then I replace the bone's `LocalTransform` with this rotation matrix:

```
Assimp.Matrix4x4 rotation = Assimp.Matrix4x4.FromRotationX(1.5708f);
bone.LocalTransform = rotation;

UpdateTransformations(bone);
```

After the bone manipulation I use following code to calculate the new `GlobalTransform` of the bone and it's child bones:

```
    public void UpdateTransformations(ModelBone bone)
    {
        this.calculateGlobalTransformation(bone);

        foreach (var child in bone.Children)
        {
            UpdateTransformations(child);
        }
    }

    private void calculateGlobalTransformation(ModelBone bone)
    {
        // Global transformation includes own local transformation ...
        bone.GlobalTransform = bone.LocalTransform;

        ModelBone parent = bone.Parent;

        while (parent != null)
        {
            // ... and all local transformations of the parent bones (recursively)
            bone.GlobalTransform = parent.LocalTransform * bone.GlobalTransform;
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
    }
```

This approach results in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Z0e.png). The transformation seems to be applied correctly to all child bones, but the manipulated bone rotates around the world space origin and not around its own local space :( I already tried to include the `GlobalTransform` translation (last row of `GlobalTransform`) into the rotation matrix before set it as the `LocalTransform`, but without success...

I hope somebody can help me with this problem!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution :) All calculations were correct except:

```
Matrix4x4 finalTransform = bone.GlobalTransform * bone.Offset;
```

The correct calculation for me is:

```
Matrix4x4 finalTransform = bone.GlobalTransform * bone.Offset;
finalTransform.transpose();
```

So it seems to be a row-major / column-major problem. My final CPU vertex skinning code is:

```
    public void PerformSmoothVertexSkinning()
    {
        // Precompute final transformation matrix for each bone
        List<Matrix4x4> FinalTransforms = new List<Matrix4x4>();

        foreach (ModelBone bone in this.BoneHierarchy.Bones)
        {
            // Multiplying a vector (e.g. vertex position/normal) by finalTransform will (from right to left):
            //      1. transform the vector from mesh space to bone space (by bone.Offset)
            //      2. transform the vector from bone space to world space (by bone.GlobalTransform)
            Matrix4x4 finalTransform = bone.GlobalTransform * bone.Offset;
            finalTransform.Transpose();

            FinalTransforms.Add(finalTransform);
        }

        foreach (Submesh submesh in this.Submeshes)
        {
            foreach (Vertex vertex in submesh.Vertices)
            {
                Vector3D newPosition = new Vector3D();
                Vector3D newNormal = new Vector3D();

                for (int i = 0; i < vertex.BoneIndices.Length; i++)
                {
                    int boneIndex = vertex.BoneIndices[i];
                    float boneWeight = vertex.BoneWeights[i];

                    // Get final transformation matrix to transform each vertex position
                    Matrix4x4 finalVertexTransform = FinalTransforms[boneIndex];

                    // Get final transformation matrix to transform each vertex normal (has to be inverted and transposed!)
                    Matrix4x4 finalNormalTransform = FinalTransforms[boneIndex];
                    finalNormalTransform.Inverse();
                    finalNormalTransform.Transpose();

                    // Calculate new vertex position and normal (average of influencing bones)
                    // Formula: newPosition += boneWeight * (finalVertexTransform * vertex.OriginalPosition);
                    //                      += boneWeight * (bone.GlobalTransform * bone.Offset * vertex.OriginalPosition);
                    // From right to left:
                    //      1. Transform vertex position from mesh space to bone space (by bone.Offset)
                    //      2. Transform vertex position from bone space to world space (by bone.GlobalTransform)
                    //      3. Apply bone weight
                    newPosition += boneWeight * (finalVertexTransform * vertex.OriginalPosition);
                    newNormal += boneWeight * (finalNormalTransform * vertex.OriginalNormal);
                }

                // Apply new vertex position and normal
                vertex.Position = newPosition;
                vertex.Normal = newNormal;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this thread is helpful for other people. Thanks for your help Sergey!

Answer (score 0):

To transform a bone you should use it's offset matrix:
http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_bone.html#a9ae5293b5c937436e4b338e20221cc2e
Offset matrix transforms from global space to bone space. If you want to rotate a bone around it's origin you should:

1. transform to bone space
2. apply rotation
3. transform to global space

So bone's global transform may be calculated like this:

```
bonesGlobalTransform = parentGlobalTransform *
        bone.offset.inverse() * 
        boneLocalTransform * 
        bone.offset;
```

So:

1. transform to bone space with offset matrix
2. apply local transform
3. transform to global space with offset.inverse() matrix

Comment: Hi. I think both calculateGlobalTransformation and vertex skinning are incorrect
You should use offset matrix in calculateGlobalTransformation  and shouldn't use it in vertex skinning

Comment: Hey Sergey, I am so happy that you replied. Almost gave up on this topic. Since my last post, I changed two little things (matrix multiplication order). So I already updated my initial post (see `calculateGlobalTransformation` and the vertex skinning code) which now reflects my current code. I was quiet sure that the calculation of the `GlobalTransform` was correct, because when displaying the translation part of `GlobalTransform` of each bone as points in my viewport, it results in this image: http://goo.gl/ncBSF4. So I thought the problem is the skinning (e.g. wrong `FinalTransform`).

Comment: In my answer you can see the calculation of bone's GlobalTransform.
You don't need FinalTransform. You should use GlobalTransform to transform vertexes.

Like this:
    `resultVertexTransformation += m_bonesGlobalTransforms[boneIdx] * boneWeight;`

Comment: Unforunately it is the first time that I read that. For example on page 13 of http://mathinfo.univ-reims.fr/image/dxMesh/extra/d3dx_skinnedmesh.pdf you can read that `FinalTransform = OffsetMatrix * CombinedMatrix` where `CombinedMatrix` is the `GlobalTransform`. And also http://graphics.ucsd.edu/courses/cse169_w05/3-Skin.htm shows in `formula (3.3)` that skinning involves the bone's GlobalTransform and the "inverse bind pose matrix" (= offset matrix). So I am a little bit confused now. Do you have a reference project with code to get a better understanding?

Comment: Also I'd like to share my code with you if you are interested (http://1drv.ms/1NFMKWt).
The points of interest are:

1) Method `calculateGlobalTransformation` in class "/Helpers/BoneHierarchy.cs"

2) Method `PerformVertexSkinning` in class "/Helpers/SkinnedModel"

3) To change the rotation of bones, see constructor of class "/ViewModels/MonitoringViewModel.cs"

Comment: I'm not sure if my solution is correct. But it works. I'll watch this thread to fix my solution if it's wrong. [Here](https://vimeo.com/153030766) you can see it in work. Unforunately I can't share my code with you